# WebSphere 7: WSCallbackHandlerImpl + InitialContext

Tags: java, websphere, jndi, jaas

When performing a programmatic login using WSCallbackHandlerImpl and there is no java.naming.provider.url set as a system property or in the jndi.properties file, one needs to call:

```
Object obj = initialContext.lookup("");
```

prior to performing the login.

Afterwards the following code works:

```
LoginContext lc = null;
try {
    lc = new LoginContext("WSLogin",
            new WSCallbackHandlerImpl("userName", "realm", "password"));
} catch (LoginException le) {
    System.out.println("Cannot create LoginContext. " + le.getMessage());
    // insert error processing code
} catch(SecurityException se) {
    System.out.printlin("Cannot create LoginContext." + se.getMessage();
    // Insert error processing
}
```

See: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/xsec_jaas.html

Neither the obj nor the initialContext gets passed to the WSCallbackHandlerImpl or the LoginContext.

According to the Javadoc, [InitialContext.lookup("")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#lookup%28javax.naming.Name%29) returns a new instance of the context.

Questions:

- Why is this empty string lookup needed in this case?
- How does WSCallbackHandlerImpl get the server URL?
- Is this WebSphere specific?

Comment: Do you have any errors, if you don't provide that lookup? What is your need, as there might be a better solutions that to use LoginModule in that way.

Comment: As mentioned in that tutorial, if the lookup is omitted then the default URL "localhost:2809" will be used instead and the authorization fails.

Comment: I used that code in the servlet in WAS 8.5, it ran fine without any  empty lookup, jndi.properties nor system property, and my default port is 2810 not 2809. Thats why I'm asking what are you trying to do and what is the exception stack trace.